# Haproxy redirect to different subdomain

Tags: redirect, rewrite, haproxy

I am trying to redirect one url **example.com/blog**  to **blog.example.com** using haproxy. I have applied following rule:

```
acl blog_path path_beg -i /blog/
redirect location http://blog.example.com/ code 301 if blog_path
```

The redirection is working fine, but there is one glitch which I am not able to solve.

If I type **example.com/blog/** in the browser, it is successfully redirected to **blog.example.com** but if I type **example.com/blog** *without / in the end* it is redirecting to **blog.example.com/blog** which should not happen and is pretty strange to me. Any idea how can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help

```
acl blog_path path_beg -i /blog/
redirect location http://blog.example.com  append-slash code 301 if blog_path
```